# Unable to execute Oracle queries | OracleException (0x80131938): ORA-00947

Tags: c#, oracle

Your help is appreciated to solve the following. Am trying to execute two Oracle queries one after another in C# code. However, I get the following error: 'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException (0x80131938): ORA-00947: not enough values in updateQuery. I checked the columns and values in the query and count is correct.

Below is the code used

```
using (con)
        {
         string verifyQuery = "select * from table x where column1='" + value1 + "'";
         using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(verifyQuery, con))
         {
           OracleDataReader drY = command.ExecuteReader();
           if (drY.HasRows)
           {}
           else
           {}
         }
         string updateQuery = "INSERT INTO table x (column) VALUES("+value + ")";
         using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(updateQuery, con))
         {
          try
            {
              OracleDataReader drX = command.ExecuteReader();
              drX = command.ExecuteReader();
              if (drX.HasRows)
              {
               drX.Read();
              }
              else
              {}
            }
            catch (OracleException OEx)
            {
             isUpdated = OEx.ToString();
            }
          }
        }
  output = isUpdated;
  con.Close();
  return output;
}
```

Comment: I  don't know c# , but it looks like the statements are different. Should not be the update like this `string updateQuery = "INSERT INTO table x (column) VALUES(" + value + ")";` I mean to have the same syntax used in the first sql statement, where there is a blank space between the + and the variable ?

Comment: Can you tell us what's the value of ```value```?

Comment: the value is string

Comment: No, that's the type of value. I wonder what the actual value is.

Comment: VARCHAR2 (20 BYTE)

Comment: No, that's the database type. ```value``` is your C# variable. Please put a breakpoint to the place where it's being used and check what the value of ```value``` actually is.

Comment: please please please don't write your SQL like that.  Please search SO and Google for "bind variables" and "SQL Injection". Because for your insert, I'll just pass as "value":  "1); delete from table where (1=" and see what happens? No more data.

Comment: Maybe your second code block should be `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` and not `command.ExecuteReader`?  Also if value is a varchar2 then you should be specifying quotes around the value like `VALUES ('" + value + "')"` but also do be mindful of the SQL Injection comment previously...